# insert on duplicate update get "new" generated id

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, database-performance, insert-update

I want to insert values,and if it exist "insert .. on duplicate update" will update it but it will not update autoincrement val with new inserted one.I heard that insert on duplicate update has some bug WHICH it always generate new id and if exists it will delete it but I want to get exactly this deleted id.(when I use last_inserted_id it just return last id of updated column which is not new inserted one)I want to update id with new inserted query should act like :insert if exists delete exist one and insert new one(with auto increment).I heard that there are replace into but it is so slow and I want just update id with new inserted id.

Comment: Then do this in two steps.  You want a bona fide `delete` followed by an `insert`.  That is not `on duplicate key update`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But I heard that insert and also delete is more slow than insert ...duplicate update

Comment: @GordonLinoff should I delete and then insert or are there other way?I need only update new values with new id

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature.

Comment: @Strawberry ok I want to use this feature and I want to get this id how I can do this?

Comment: Test REPLACE speed. It should not be much slower. It is exactly, what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect, you're playing with fire if you try to carry out fancy update logic with autoincrement columns.

If you need a new autoincrement id in a row when you update it, then just delete the old row and insert the new one like Gordon said.

Under some database workloads that may be slightly slower than using `insert on duplicate key update`. But unless your table contains at least 100 megarows, or unless you're doing at least 10 of these operations per second all day and all night, the performance difference will be trivial.  If you do have that kind of database size or workload, ask your database administrator for advice.

`REPLACE` = `DELETE`, then `INSERT`.  IODKU never deletes.  Each requires you to specify the columns of some `UNIQUE` key so that it knows what row to work with.  A subtle point:  If there are multiple `UNIQUE` keys, `REPLACE` may delete multiple rows, then insert only one.

IODKU can get the id (either existing or new) by using `... UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), ...`.

Comment: Ok I will do this but I want to learn that which cases on duplicate is more slow than delete and insert?

Comment: `REPLACE` has to do more work, so it is likely to always be slower.  I added some more info to the answer.

Comment: you said LAST_INSERTED_ID I want to get something like this to update id with last one which is generated by "INSERT ... on duplicate update" but it gave me id itself of updated elem(old one)

Comment: @RickJames  you wroted LAST_INSERTED_ID I want to get something like this to update id with last one which is generated by "INSERT ... on duplicate update" but it gave me id itself of updated elem(old one)

Comment: is it good To delete and again insert for only to getting new generated id  from INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: If you want new id, use `REPLACE`; if you want speed, use IODKU.

Comment: Spelling error (by me):  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` - [_link_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: _Why_ do you want a new id?

Comment: @RickJames because I created some kind of notification system and I created view of this notification system with scroll when user scroll on notificatoin div it will get next notifications but I need final_notify id for each notification for showing them order by new ones because notification date is from another tables and depend on notification type(as I said before it is really complex I cant continue because I have not enough place to write it) but I need this new id.
Also should I use insert and delete or replace?Are there performance different?

Comment: I have not benchmarked it, but I expect `REPLACE` to be optimal.  You do need some other `UNIQUE` key to make `REPLACE` work.